# Let $C_n $ be the number of ways for $n$ people to form several nonempty lines and then to arrange these lines in a circular order.

Tags: combinatorics

Let $C_n$ be the number of ways for $n$ people to form several nonempty lines, and then to arrange these lines in a circular order. Find a closed formula for $C_n$.

I was thinking to use either exponential or compositional formula, but I am very unsure about this problem. Please help me on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exponential generating function for a nonempty line is $x/(1-x)$. The egf for forming a linear order of $k$ non-empty lines is therefore $(x/(1-x))^k$; we must then divide by $k$ to make this a cyclic order. Summing over $k$, and recalling $\sum_{k\ge1}y^k/k=-\log(1-y)$, we get the egf for $C_n$ is $-\log(1-x/(1-x))$. I leave it to you to extract the formula for $C_n$.